# Asked a question before signing up and can not sign in back

Tags: discussion, design

Yesterday I asked [my first question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119543/einstein-summation-and-traditional-form-of-partial-derivative-of-implicit-functi) on mathematica.stackexchange, but being as an unregistered user at that moment.

Then I confirmed my email and would like to express my gratitude and note the correct answer, but it seems that following the link from my email I have created [a new account](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/41347/oleg) and still can not access [the unregistered one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/41332/oleg)

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how could I work out this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/combine-two-users?rq=1) may be of help.